# Selenium C#, cannot find table cell to click link

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to click a clickable cell in a table (the cells have links) but I cannot even get the test to find the cells themselves. I can make the iFrame active but cannot find the cells, i.e. I navigate to the frame using.

```
IWebElement objecElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='AreaID2_iframe']"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(objecElement);
```

but then the following does not find a table cell

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='lwDataGrid_r_0_c_5']"));
```

The table format is as follows in the following link below :-

[image: https]

Any help much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: What do you mean can't find?? Is there any exception??

Answer (score 0):

Try using proper selectors i.e.

```
IWebElement objecElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("AreaID2_iframe"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(objecElement);

var tableRow = driver.FindElements(By.Id("lwDataGrid_r_0_c_5"));
```

Put a break point after `tableRow`and see if it finds the element?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is timing issue, you should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until table is loaded and desire element is visible as below :-

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("AreaID2_iframe"));

IWebElement row = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("lwDataGrid_r_0_c_5")));
```